# Disable animations in Angular Material 2 but keep using animations in the rest of the application

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-animations

I want to disable all the animations to the Angular Material 2, but when I import the `NoopAnimationsModule` it also prevents me for using the Angular Animation module in the rest of my app code.
I'd like to be able to animate certain things of my app, but disable the animation for Angular Material 2.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Edit: I want to disable all the animations but the ripple effect.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the material components provide api to disable ripple effect. As far as I know, it's not possible to completely turn off animation for material2.

`disableRipple` property is available for

- checkbox
- radio
- buttons
- slider toggle
- tabs
- button

Comment: Thank you @Nehal, I was aware of disabling the ripple effect, but in my case I want to maintain the ripple, but disable the other material animations while keeping the ability to use the angular animation module in my own code.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!