# Angular Material - Disable mat-sidenav transition animation but keep children animations?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I have an Angular app with a `mat-sidenav` that's structured like this:

```html
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav [mode]="'side'">
        <!-- Sidenav content -->
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <!-- Main content -->
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I'd like to disable the transition animation for the `mat-sidenav` but keep the sidenav content's animations (e.g. for a `mat-vertical-stepper`). However, I haven't been able to find a way to do this.

So far, I've found [this similar GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/1126), but the fixes described there seem to disable the sidenav content's animations too. For example, I've tried the following:

```html
<mat-sidenav-container [@.disabled]="true">
    <mat-sidenav [mode]="'side'">
        <!-- Sidenav content -->
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <!-- Main content -->
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

which disables the sidenav transition animation, but also disables all other animations. The following doesn't seem to work either:

```html
<mat-sidenav-container [@.disabled]="true">
    <mat-sidenav [mode]="'side'" [@.disabled]="false">
        <!-- Sidenav content -->
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content [@.disabled]="false">
        <!-- Main content -->
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I've also found [this article in Angular's documentation](https://angular.io/api/animations/trigger#overriding-disablement-of-inner-animations), but it seems very complicated and I can't figure out how to apply it to components without custom animations (like the `mat-vertical-stepper`).

Is there any easy way to disable a `mat-sidenav`'s transition animation while still keeping its children's animations?

Comment: what do you mean by "disable transition animation", could you elaborate more?

Comment: I want the sidenav to close instantly instead of taking 400ms to slide away like how it currently does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a workaround.
Temporarily disable it.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6enqwb-yxaggq)

in HTML:

```
<mat-sidenav-container [@.disabled]="temporaryDisabled">
  <mat-sidenav [mode]="'side'" #sidenav> 
    Sidenav content
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <div class="header">
      <button mat-stroke-button (click)="toggle()">toggle sidenav</button>
    </div>
    <div class="stepper">
      <mat-vertical-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper >
        (... stepper codes ...)
      </mat-vertical-stepper>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

in .ts file:

```
temporaryDisabled: boolean = false;
toggle(){
  this.temporaryDisabled = true;
  this.sidenav.toggle();
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.temporaryDisabled = false;
  },10);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

```
using Angular module `NoopAnimationsModule`
```

1  Import
import {NoopAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

2 ensure you add it to NgModule

```
@NgModule({      
  imports: [NoopAnimationsModule]...      
})
export class YourMaterialModule { }
```

To remove animation/transition on some specific components you can *also* do it via CSS like this

```
.mat-sidenav{ transition: none; }
```

Check out this for [disableRipple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44855209/6085193) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60059858/6085193)

Comment: Neither of these work for me. The first one disables all animations on the website while I only want to disable the transition animation, and the second one just doesn't do anything